# Libraries can not load my php library

Tags: theming

This following is my php library location:

`sites/all/libraries/Baidu-Push-SDK-Php`

I try to implement  `hook_libraries_info()`:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_libraries_info().
 */

function baidu_push_services_libraries_info() {
  $libraries = array();

  $libraries['Baidu-Push-SDK-Php'] = array(
      'name' => 'Baidu Push SDK',
      'vendor url' => 'http://developer.baidu.com/',
      'download url' => 'http://developer.baidu.com/',
      'version arguments' => array(
        'file' => 'change_log',
        'pattern' => '([0-9\.]+)',
        'lines' => 14,
      ),
      'files' => array(
        'php' => array(
          'Channel.class.php',
        ),
      ),
    );

  return $libraries;
}
```

Then I try to load my library:

```
$baidu_push = libraries_load("Baidu-Push-SDK-Php");
```

But It show me:

```
The <em class="placeholder">BaiduPushSDK</em> library could not be found.
```